# Viewing ppt slides part by part

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

Is it possible to view ppt file using Apache POI as if viewing it by PowerPoint or LibreOffice Impress?

I find out how to show presentation as paged one but my presentation contains "effects" so each paragraph is viewing independently (eg. 5 effects per page).

What I need is to know how many "effects" is inbuild id proper slide or view slide "effect after effect".

I hope that it is quite clear to understand my question.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried

Comment: I haven't implemented effects yet - the common sl rendering is using all shapes even if they would be hidden again when all effects for a given slide are finished.